# Mass Dropped on Scale

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

When a mass is dropped onto something like a bathroom scale, the reading on the scale temporarily exceeds the actual weight of the mass. How do I explain this using forces and a force body diagram?
Also, let's say instead of a mass and a scale, its just a person, a ball, and a scale. The person is standing on the scale with the ball in hand and throws it up in the air. When the person catches the ball, should the scale also read a value greater than the weight of the human and the ball combined? Is the reasoning for this the same as the mass and scale example?

Edit: Could the explanation be that at the instantaneous moment when the mass comes in contact with the scale, there is an instantaneous force caused by the impulse?

Comment: Force = mass * acceleration. The scale can de-accelerate the mass quickly

Comment: Thin of the dp/dt for of force, an impulse. It adds or subtracts during dt.

Comment: Have you read about variable mass systems??

Answer (score 1):

Forces must always balance. A force is required to support a stationary mass on a bathroom scale. An additional force is required to effect the deceleration of a mass if it has vertical downward motion as it makes contact with the bathroom scale surface.

Dropping the mass onto the bathroom scale:
$$F = mg + ma \tag1$$
where m is the kg mass of the mass dropped on the bathroom scale, g is gravitational acceleration, and
$$a = \Delta v/\Delta t \tag2$$
where $v$ and $t$ are velocity and time. The maximum $a$ determines the maximum force indicated on the scale. The heavier the ball, the harder the scale surface and the stiffer the scale's spring, the higher $F$ will be (figure below).

When the person is catching the ball, the person is as the stationary mass above, and the ball has a stationary and decelerating component. See figure below.

[image: mass dropped onto scale]